# Debugging Windows 10 IoT Core Background application directly on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10-iot-core

While i'm trying to debug a Windows 10 IoT Core Background app on my Windows 10 dev environment i got this error message:

> Unable to activate Windows Store app "name of my
>   app_oquwheiuqheiuwqh!App". The activation request failed with error
>   "This program is blocked by group policy. For more infornation,
>   contact your system administrator".

But...  i'm administrator on such host.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You're not supposed to run Background app directly on Windows 10. You can only run/debug it on headless devices, like Windows 10 IoT Core.

See to https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/headlessmode

BackgroundTask app is something similar to so-called windows services in Windows 10.

Besides, it might be a good idea to check your task registration in project manifest file, in the Extension section, you should see something similiar to

```
  <Extensions>
    <Extension Category="windows.backgroundTasks" EntryPoint="BackgroundApplication.StartupTask">
      <BackgroundTasks>
        <iot:Task Type="startup" />
      </BackgroundTasks>
    </Extension>
  </Extensions>
```

Mark the iot key word, probably a clue for such task only runs on Windows IoT Core.

The warning message implies this is something related to group policy settings, but I don't think it's worth any effort to hack the group policy, since your Windows 10 can not run as headless-mode.